# Converting a DateTime Object to an String

Tags: java, date

I have a simple question. How can I convert an ISO-8601 Date to an String?
I'm using a Date with the following format: `2019-02-05T08:21:15.000+01:00` and want to convert this Date Object to an String. I tried the following:

```java
String startString = (String) jsonObjectMap2.get("created_on"); 
//startString = "2019-02-21T09:47:58.699004+00:00"`
```

```java
DateTime start = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime(startString);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ+|-hh:mm"); 
String formatedStartString = dateFormat.format(start);`
```

But Iam getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date.

What is the corrrect form of the DateFormat? I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Please note that when asking about exceptions you should _always_ post the entire stacktrace (nicely formatted please).

Comment: As for your question: `DateFormat.format()` doesn't accept `DateTime` instances, just `Date` or `Number`. `ISODateTimeFormat` indicates you are using JodaTime and thus you'd need to use JodaTime to format the parsed date. Try using JoadTime's `DateTimeFormat.forPattern(/*your pattern*/).print(start)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: Where does class `DateTime` come from - are you using Joda Time? (It's not a class from the standard Java library).

Comment: There’s something I don’t understand here. You are getting a string from `jsonObjectMap2` and you say you want a string. Is there anything missing at all? What?

Comment: When you’re already using Joda-Time, there’s no point in also struggling with the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat`. Joda-Time can do your formatting (if you need any at all). The other good option is to follow the suggestion from [the Joda-Time home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/): migrate entirely to java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: If using Joda-Time in your code sample, say so in your Question, or add a tag.

Comment: Paste your the message you got, *Cannot format given Object as a Date*, into your search engine and get lots of hits.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-02-21T09:47:58.699004+00:00" )
```

## java.time

What class is `DateTime`? If you are using Joda-Time, know that the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance-mode. Its creator, Stephen Colbourne, went on to lead JSR 310 and implement the *java.time* classes built into Java.

## No need for formatting pattern

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
String input = "2019-02-21T09:47:58.699004+00:00" ;  // Standard ISO 8601 format.
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

Your input string indicates an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) but not a time zone. So the appropriate class to represent this value is `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

why not use toString() on your DateTime object?

Comment: This should have been posted as a Comment rather than an Answer.

Comment: I am new in posting on stackoverflow,  I was maybe misguided by the title "Converting a DateTime Object to an String", so I proposed a solution to exactly that issue

Comment: @BasilBourque he can't comment yet

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas alluded to in the comments, `DateTime.format()` consumes a `Date` object, not a `DateTime` object; hence the `IllegalArgumentException`. Judging by the format of your date you could try parsing your `startString` using the in-built `java.time.ZonedDateTime` class:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(startString) //it can parse ISO-8601 date-times
```

You could then format your `dateTime` object using `java.time.DateTimeFormatter`'s static `ofPattern()` method which takes a `String` pattern to apply to your date-time and returns the formatted date as a String:

```
String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ+|-hh:mm"));
```

---

**EDIT**

As Basil pointed out, the OP's `DateTime` object includes a time offset which is not necessarily a time zone offset--as is represented by the `ZonedDateTime` class. Thus the most appropriate class to use in this scenario is `OffsetDateTime` which provides the same capabilities but is more suited for the given use case. See [Basil Bourque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54815278/3864051)

Comment: No, `ZonedDateTime` is not appropriate here. The input string of "2019-02-21T09:47:58.699004+00:00" indicates an offset-from-UTC but not a time zone. So the best fit is `OffsetDateTime` class: `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-02-21T09:47:58.699004+00:00" )`

Comment: @BasilBourque You're right, hadn't used `OffsetDateTime` before so `ZonedDateTime` immediately came to mind

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain that this will solve your problem, 
But mm should be uppercase i.e MM, 
Because MM describes months while mm describes minutes.

see the following code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ+|- 
    hh:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following to work for me

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS[XXX]");
String formatted = zonedDateTime.format(dateTimeFormatter);
```

Comment: (A) No need to specify a formatting pattern. Standard ISO 8601 strings such as this input can be parsed by default with *java.time* classes. (B) No `ZonedDateTime` is the wrong class for this input. The `OffsetDateTime` class is appropriate for an input with an offset-from-UTC but not a time zone.